# i have a dataframe with more than 2000 rows. From the df, i need to create a schema in r

Tags: r, dataframe, schema, grouping, rows

The format is as follows: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5GLA.png)

I need to create the following schema for the df.
I may have 2 or more instruction for an item.

{
Section: Section1,
Title: Power Cables
List_of_Instruction: [
{
Instruction: information provided
},
]
List_of_items:[
{
Product: Item1,
Unit:10,
Rate: 100
},
{
Product: Item2,
Unit:2,
Rate: 2000
}
]
List_of_instruction:[
{
Instruction:information 1.0
},
]
List_of_items:[
{
Product:item.1.0,
Unit:5,
Rate:10
}
],
Title: Cable Containment,
List_of_instruction:[
{
Instruction: information
}
],
List_of_items:[
{
Product:item,
Unit:100,
Rate:4
}
]

```
} ,
```

{
Section: ….
Title: ….
}

Comment: Its not clear how to setup Instruction. There are two candidates, both _Information provided_ and _Information 1.0_ , how do you select one above the other?

Comment: It will be easier for the community to help if you can add the table referred to in the question as a text so that one can replicate it. Also, avoid adding images as hyperlinks. You can embed them in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one take, I assume you want to group under Section, Title and Instruction, those are listed on the top level in each segment, and it makes senes from your data.

```r
d <- read.csv(text=
"Description,Unit,Rate,isItem,IsSection,IsInstruction,IsTitle,sheetname
Section1,NA,NA,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,Sheet1
Power Cables,NA,NA,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,Sheet1
Information Provided,NA,NA,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,Sheet1
Item1,10,100,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,Sheet1
Item2,2,2000,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,Sheet1
Information 1.0,NA,NA,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,Sheet1
Item1.0,5,10,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,Sheet1
Cable containment,NA,NA,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,Sheet1
Information,NA,NA,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,Sheet1
item,100,4,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,Sheet1
Section2,NA,NA,NA,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,Sheet1
Pipe,NA,NA,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,Sheet1
details,NA,NA,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,Sheet1
Items4,7,500,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,Sheet1
",header=TRUE)

library(jsonlite)
library(zoo)

d2 <- d %>% mutate( Section = na.locf( ifelse( IsSection, Description, NA ) ) ) %>%
    group_by( Section ) %>%
    mutate( Title = na.locf( ifelse( IsTitle, Description, NA ), na.rm=FALSE ) ) %>%
    group_by( Section, Title ) %>%
    mutate( Instruction = na.locf( ifelse( IsInstruction, Description, NA ), na.rm=FALSE ) )

## A helper function to do the heavy finesse work:
make.segment <- function(d) {
    with(
        d,
        list(
            Section = Section[1],
            Title = Title[1],
            Instruction = Instruction[1],
            List_of_items =
                d %>% filter( isItem ) %>%
                rename( Product=Description ) %>%
                select( Product, Unit, Rate ) %>%
                apply( 1, as.list )
        )
    )
}

## Standard dplyr work to do the heavy lifting:
l <- d2 %>% filter( !is.na(Title) & !is.na(Instruction) ) %>%
    group_by( Section, Title, Instruction ) %>%
    do( segment = make.segment(.) ) %>%
    pull( segment ) %>%
    as.list

toJSON( l, pretty=TRUE, auto_unbox=TRUE )
```

Your example does show json, so I assume that is what you want out, this produces:

```json
[
  {
    "Section": "Section1",
    "Title": "Cable containment",
    "Instruction": "Information",
    "List_of_items": [
      {
        "Product": "item",
        "Unit": "100",
        "Rate": "4"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Section": "Section1",
    "Title": "Power Cables",
    "Instruction": "Information 1.0",
    "List_of_items": [
      {
        "Product": "Item1.0",
        "Unit": "5",
        "Rate": "10"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Section": "Section1",
    "Title": "Power Cables",
    "Instruction": "Information Provided",
    "List_of_items": [
      {
        "Product": "Item1",
        "Unit": "10",
        "Rate": " 100"
      },
      {
        "Product": "Item2",
        "Unit": " 2",
        "Rate": "2000"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Section": "Section2",
    "Title": "Pipe",
    "Instruction": "details",
    "List_of_items": [
      {
        "Product": "Items4",
        "Unit": "7",
        "Rate": "500"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: hm I see numbers got turned into strings ill have to look at this in more detail later

Comment: I tried the code however in list_of_items, my data are repeated.

Comment: The schema is becoming as :  {
    "Section": "Section1",
    "Title": "Power Cables",
    "Instruction": "Information Provided",
    "List_of_items": [
      {
        "Product": "Item1",
        "Unit": "10",
        "Rate": " 100"
      },                                                                                                                                   
     {
        "Product": "Item1",
        "Unit": "10",
        "Rate": " 100"
      },
      {
        "Product": "Item2",
        "Unit": " 2",
        "Rate": "2000"
      }
    ]
  },